# List all the dropbox files and folder using dropbox API and download file clicked in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have researched alot on google and also read the steps mentioned at www.dropbox.com, but I didn't found any way to list all the files and folders of dropbox in my application using dropbox API.. I know how to download a file from dropbox and also how to upload a file to dropbox.

But anyone pls suggest me that Is this possible to list all the files and folder of dropbox and whenever you click on any file then that file starts downloading and save into your sdcard..

Anyone pls help me out with some sample ....plsss

Answer (score 17, accepted):

simple sample.

```
Entry entries = mApi.metadata(Path, 100, null, true, null);

for (Entry e : entries.contents) {
    if (!e.isDeleted) {
        Log.i("Is Folder",String.valueOf(e.isDir));
        Log.i("Item Name",e.fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are some reasons this would give me a NullPointerException? Been trying to get it to work but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: What is `Path` in this case? `Path` of what? I want to list all the directories and files and then let the user decide which one to download.

Comment: This answer is over 4 years old and possibly no longer relevant due to the Dropbox API being upgraded to V2. You should check the official documentation of the version you are using for an explanation on which parameters the methods expect.

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`/metadata`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#metadata) method with the `list` parameter set to `true` to get all the information about a folder and its contents.

Comment: If possible, can you please provide me this with an example?

Comment: If you have already used the [Dropbox SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk), you can take a look at [`DropboxAPI.metadata`](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#metadata(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String)) method